# Getting Size Exceeded Exception while storing Dataframe into MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark, graphframes

I am trying to store Apache Spark Dataframe into MongoDB using Scala but getting Caused by: org.bson.BsonMaximumSizeExceededException: Payload document size is larger than maximum of 16777216. exception while storing dataframe into MongoDB

**Code Snippet:**

```
 val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .appName("User Network Graph")
      .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://mongo/socio.d3raw")
      .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://mongo/socio.d3raw")
      .master("yarn").getOrCreate()

 val rawD3str=seqGraph.toDF()

 MongoSpark.write(rawD3str).option("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://mongo/socio" 
   ).option("collection","d3raw").mode("append").save()
```

**Error stack trace**
0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 332.0 (TID 11617, hadoop-node022, executor 1): org.bson.BsonMaximumSizeExceededException: Payload document size is larger than maximum of 16777216.
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.BsonWriterHelper.writePayload(BsonWriterHelper.java:68)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandMessage.encodeMessageBodyWithMetadata(CommandMessage.java:147)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.RequestMessage.encode(RequestMessage.java:138)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandMessage.encode(CommandMessage.java:61)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:248)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.sendAndReceive(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:99)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.sendAndReceive(DefaultConnectionPool.java:450)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandProtocolImpl.execute(CommandProtocolImpl.java:72)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor.execute(DefaultServer.java:226)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerConnection.executeProtocol(DefaultServerConnection.java:269)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerConnection.command(DefaultServerConnection.java:131)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.executeCommand(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:435)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.executeBulkWriteBatch(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:261)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.access$700(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:72)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation$1.call(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:205)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation$1.call(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:196)
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.wi

Comment: How to overcome this MongoDB size limit while working with Apache Spark ? Can we use GridFS to store  dataframe with size > 16MB

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB has a 16MB document size limit.  See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#document-size-limit for more details.  It sounds like what you're trying to save is larger than 16 MB.

Comment: ..Looking for a solution to overcome MongoDB's size limit issue which i am getting while storing Apache Spark Dataframe into MongoDB

Comment: I don't have experience with Apache Spark Dataframe, so I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to import.  One thing you could try is using GridFS:  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/.  Another option is store large files outside of the database in something like an S3 bucket:  https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/handling-files-using-mongodb-stitch-and-aws-s3